# Downloading a file with response doesn't show a filesize

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have this piece of code in a function:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.xml");
// Put xml into response here
Response.End();
```

And this works, but, when it, it doesn't show a file size, in firefox it shows the filesize -1 and in chrome and ie it doesn't show a file size at all. How can I show the file size?

Comment: You need an additional header `Content-Length: xxxx` (where 'xxxx' is file size in bytes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try giving this:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", someBytes.Length.ToString());
```

If the content-length is set the web browser will show a progress bar while downloading. This is a very important usability feature for medium and large files, and you really want it. You want your user to know how far along they are, so they don't cancel the download and start it over, or worse just abandon your site.
[Refer](http://tech.hickorywind.org/articles/2008/05/23/content-length-mostly-does-not-matter-the-reverse-bob-barker-rule)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I stream the output into Response.Output. Is there any way I can get the size of Response.Output?

Comment: do you used `Response.OutputStream.Length` ? i have not tried this one but let me know if this helps ?

Comment: I've created a separate question for this because it's a different issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385689/get-response-output-size

Answer (score 1):

If your Response is of type [System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true), you can insert a  Content-Length header by using:

```
response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = <length in bytes>;
```

If you are stream a file your code could look like:

```
FileStream fileStream = File.Open("<source file name>", FileMode.Open);
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = fileStream.Length;
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = 
  new MediaTypeHeaderValue("<media type e.g. application/zip>");
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
  new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("file")
    {
      FileName = "<destination file name>"
    };
return response;
```