# Get Response.output size?

Tags: asp.net

My code is now like this:

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataSet));
xmlSerializer.Serialize(Response.Output, ds);
```

After that I want to show the size, but this gives me an error:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", Response.OutputStream.Length.ToString());
```

The error is

```
NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code
```

Comment: The underlying stream does not support `Length`. Not much you can do about it.

Comment: @Oded I know it doesn't support length, that's why I'm asking how I can get he size of the Response.Ouput object. Your response doesn't add anything of value.

Answer (score 2):

The `Response.OutputStream` does not support a `Length` property; you can not get the length. One problem is, that `Stream` could outlive the `Response` if, as is usually the case, `Keep-Alive` is enabled. That's why you can't get a `Length` at all... But...

Also note that the Stream here is sending more than just the content - it's also sending the headers. That makes it wholly inappropriate to use how you are hoping to use it (since your resulting `Content-Length` header would be incorrect.) So even if you could get the `Length`, it would not be what you want.

And it's impossible again, anyway: The header you are attempting to set is *part of* what would be going out on that `Stream`.... see the problem?

FosterZ has given you a different route to go to try to solve this problem, though; you need to get the length of what you really want to measure - not of the stream.

Comment: So there is no way to pass the length of a generated file?

Comment: You need to pass the length of the *file*. That's not what you are doing. The `Stream` you are writing the file to is not the same thing as the file itself. Get the length of the *file itself* to pass to that code.

Answer (score 1):

I was doin' this before long time mine code was like this below, you may get some idea or hint:

```
string output = encoding.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
memoryStream  = new MemoryStream(output.Length);

byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(output);
//buffer.Length(); is this the length you want ?
```